# ERROR in ./app/main.js Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:18)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when i use 'webpack' ,The error  below....

ERROR in ./app/main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:18)

```
   8 | 
   9 | function main(){
> 10 |   ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('app'));
     |                   ^
  11 | }
  12 | main();
  13 |
```

**component.jsx**

```
<div><i>   import React from 'react';
     export default class Hello extends React.Component {
       render() {
       return (<h1>Hello World---component.jsx</h1>)
      }
  }</i></div>
```

**main.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  import Hello from './component.jsx';

   function main(){
    ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('app'));
  }
  main();
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "enviromentproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "一个用来做环境搭建的项目测试",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot --content-base build"
  },
  "author": "jkwu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^2.0.7",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "hexo-deployer-git": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: why are u writing your component.jsx file in such a way. U can write it in a simpler way... I think the syntax u get is due to way u are writing ur code in component.jsx file.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to import inside a div? It should be done outside, in the beginning of the .jsx file

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your component.jsx shouldn't be inside `html` tags

Simple write

```
import React from 'react';
     export default class Hello extends React.Component {
       render() {
       return (<h1>Hello World---component.jsx</h1>)
      }
  }
```

Secondly and more importantly make sure you specify babel as a loader for your jsx in your webpack config

```
module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        exclude : /node_modules/,
        loader : 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Also it doesn't cause a problem but you don't need to call your `ReactDOM.render()` inside a function

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
       render() {
       return (<h1>Hello World---component.jsx</h1>)
      }
  }

    ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "babel-preset-react"

npm install babel-preset-react
and add "presets" option to babel-loader in your webpack.config.js

(or you can add it to your .babelrc or package.js: http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/)

Here is an example webpack.config.js:

```
{ 
    test: /\.jsx?$/,         // Match both .js and .jsx files
    exclude: /node_modules/, 
    loader: "babel", 
    query:
    {
        presets:['react']
    }
}
```

then: npm install react-dom --save
at main.js
import { render } from 'react-dom';

use this render